# Passing Coldfusion query result to Form

Tags: forms, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfquery, cfform

I have two Coldfusion templates (`getdata.cfm` and `generate.cfm`).  The first template `getdata.cfm` will retrieve from a database with a query, in addition to other tasks.  It will retrieve exactly 16 rows of data and each row will have 8 fields. Such as this:

```
<cfquery datasource="xyz name="lista">
SELECT n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,n7,n8
FROM atable
WHERE product = "abc"
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 16
</cfquery>
```

The second template will generate some random numbers and compare them against these 16 rows.  There is a Refresh button on the second template to regenerate the numbers.  This is how I would like it to work.

However, right now the only way for it to work is having the database `<cfquery>` in the second template, `generate.cfm`  That means every time I press Refresh, it will access the database, retrieve the same 16 rows every time, and generate the random numbers.  This is not ideal.  Because the 16 rows are the same, it makes no sense to retrieve them every time a new set of random numbers get generated.  It would be best to get them once, in the first template and somehow pass them to the second template.  The 16 sets of numbers will need to be displayed on the screen at all times.  The matched and unmatched numbers need to be shown.

How can I pass the whole query result from the first template to the second one without having to pass the 16 records as 16 lists via the form as form fields?  Is this even possible?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

- Generate a set of random numbers.
- Compare those numbers against a static set of data.
- Repeat.

Do you need to do the comparison in the application (CFML) code? Can you generate the set of random numbers and send them to the DB as part of the query in a single request? That way, you get the records from the DB that match your set of numbers and not all 16.

Then every refresh would send the new set of random numbers to the DB, returning only the relevant data.

Alternately, you can use `cfquery` with the `cachedWithin` attribute in order to store the results of the query into memory for a specific amount of time while refreshing your random set of numbers.

https://cfdocs.org/cfquery

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the 16 sets of numbers need to be displayed on the second template.  I try to avoid using the cache if I can to save the server's memory :)

Comment: I do need to do the comparison in the application and show the matched and unmatched results.

Comment: You can use AJAX to call a function that gets the random numbers and javascript to compare them to whatever is in the query.  However, in the overall scheme of things, there is also value to simplicity which means that either query caching or repeated database calls might not be all that bad.